# How to write SpannableString to parcel?

Tags: android, string, parcelable, spannablestring

In my application I have dialog which consists few `SpannableString` objects. Because this is dialog, I need to be able to store it when user leaves application and comes back to it later on.

But the problem is how can I write `SpannableString` into Parcel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I actually found out some way to do it using already existing functions, although I am not sure if it works for all type of spans, or just for those that I am using.

Inside write parcel methos you have to add

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    TextUtils.writeToParcel(mSpannableString, dest, flags);
}
```

and next in order to extract SpannableString out of Parcel you should use this

```
public CustomConstructor(Parcel parcel) {
    mSpannableString = (SpannableString) TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TextUtils.writeToParcel()` method

Supporting spans in TextUtils

`TextUtils
line 555-604
public static final int ALIGMENT_SPAN = 1;
......`

Answer (score 1):

If you use Parcelize, you can save a already processed Spannable into the parcelized data class as a CharSequence. It will work if you'll use it later.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on [Kandyzowana Papaja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4605121/kandyzowana-papaja) answer you can use [Kotlin Extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) and have your SpannableString inside you Parcelable and do things like you would for normal Strings.

**Extension function**

```
import android.os.Parcel
import android.text.SpannableString
import android.text.TextUtils

fun Parcel.writeSpannableString(spannableString: SpannableString?, flags: Int) {
    TextUtils.writeToParcel(spannableString, this, flags)
}

fun Parcel.readSpannableString() : SpannableString? {
    return TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR.createFromParcel(this) as SpannableString?
}
```

**Parcelable implementation**

```
import <your.path.to.extension.file>.readSpannableString
import <your.path.to.extension.file>.writeSpannableString

[...]

private constructor(parcel: Parcel) : super(parcel) {
    someString = parcel.readString()
    someInteger = parcel.readInt()
    someSpannableString = parcel.readSpannableString() // using extension function
}

override fun writeToParcel(out: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    super.writeToParcel(out, flags)
    out.writeString(someString)
    out.writeInt(someInteger)
    out.writeSpannableString(someSpannableString, flags) // using extension function
}
```

But be careful. I'm pretty sure this won't work for the `@Parcelize` annotation for Kotlin's [automatic Parcelable generation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#parcelable-implementations-generator).

Answer (score -2):

SpannableString is not parceable so you won't be able to save them and recreate them using parcels. What you can do instead is save the text and spans separately. The text and spans are parceable so they will be fine when you recreate them.

Comment: how is that there is no function inside any utils class to do such thing? sorry for this rhetorical question...

Comment: I wish I had an answer for you but I really don't. Lol